# problem with arrays in python with the same function

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm having A VERY STRANGE scenario, I've simplified the code, but having the 
SAME issues.

```
def write_to_bf_of_lpr(bf_source, bf_destination, lpr_index, start, length):
    for x in range(length):
        bf_destination[lpr_index][start + x] = bf_source[start + x]

source = ['a','b','c','d','e']

destination = [[0]*5]*3
dets2=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

for x in range(1):
    write_to_bf_of_lpr(bf_source=source,bf_destination=dets2,lpr_index=x,start=1,length=2)

for x in range(1):
    write_to_bf_of_lpr(bf_source=source,bf_destination=destination,lpr_index=x,start=1,length=2)
```

this code is quite simple to understand, what I wish to do is only change specific  array each time (or iteration).

Now: when I write in shorented version: `destination = [[0]*5]*3`
it is changing ALL the arrays within SINGLE iteration.

When I write in the LONG version (which is not preferable ) I get the CORRECT version.

You can see that `dest2` is the correct, while `destination` is the wrong answer.

The funny thing is, that I simply COPIED the values from the short version... and there's different result...

Is it Pycharm bug, python, or am i missing something?
please see screenshot of the output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you define an array the way you have, you're basically creating copies of the reference which points to `[0]*5` which means if you change one, they all change. You can do what you want in you're using numpy, this way when you change one index, only that index changes.

```
import numpy as np

destination = np.zeros((3, 5))
```

You can also do it without numpy as follows:

`destination = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!